# Image compression Operations without edges blurring

Tags: compression, image-compression

I'm looking for some image compression operations, preferably simple in nature, that provide moderate compression ratios while preserving the edges in the images.

Please note that algorithms like JPEG which pack multiple operations are not applicable (unfortunately).

Comment: What are your requirements? Do you need to do it programatically? Do you need it in a supported format? How are you storing it?

Comment: PNG compression is lossless.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using numpy, I suggest you take a look at  the scipy.misc.imsave method

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.misc.imsave.html

You can easily store your data in png without any loss and with compression ratios along the ranges you mentioned in your comment, e.g.,

```
rgb = np.zeros((255, 255, 3), dtype=np.uint8)
rgb[..., 0] = np.arange(255)
rgb[..., 1] = 55
rgb[..., 2] = 1 - np.arange(255)
imsave('/tmp/rgb_gradient.png', rgb)
```

**Edit after comment 1**:
It is really difficult to answer this question because of the lack of specifics.

Retaining a compressed version of the image in memory will certainly slow down your processing, as you will either need to decode and encode relevant parts of the image in each operation, or you'll need to use very specific algorithms that allow you to access and modify pixel values in the compressed domain (e.g., http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/232097/).

Now, to answer your question, the simplest way I can think is to use Huffman coding (https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/greedy-algorithms-set-3-huffman-coding/) and store the codewords in memory. You will probably need to encode groups of pixels together so that each byte of codewords results in more than one pixel (and hence you could have any real compression). Otherwise, you'd need to find a way to efficiently pack small codewords (say 2 or 3 bits) together, which will certainly hinder your ability to read and write individual pixel values.